# Android Spinners And Buttons

Tags: android

I have an array of Buttons and Array with my Spinners.I am trying to set the Buttons text to the selected Spinners Text.Can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
for(int i=0;i<theSpinners.length;i++){
       theSpinners[i].setSelection(theArray[i]);
       theButtons[i].setText(theSpinners[i].getSelectedItemPosition());
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What's wrong with your output?  Error?  Wrong value?  No value?

Comment: Your arrays are not initialized the way you think, based on your feedback.  Obviously one of them is not set to an object.  Check the code where you are populating theSpinners, theButtons and theArray.

Comment: Yeah I had set a wrong index in my Button Array.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSelectedItemPosition()` returns an integer, so setText won't behave as you want. You will want do do something like this...

```
theButtons[i].setText(String.valueOf(theSpinners[i].getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

... if what you want is setting the index of the spinner. Or maybe, you want to use the `getSelectedItem` method...

```
theButtons[i].setText(theSpinners[i].getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: I am getting a nullPointerException with theButtons[i].setText(theSpinners[i].getSelectedItem().toString());

Comment: If you get a NPE, then check what's null... it could be the buttons array or the spinners array.

Comment: Hah.Yeah I set a wrong index when setting up my Button Array.